Splitting multivariate time series data to avoid data leakage in PyTorch?
I have two predictors A and B with the goal to predict target (y) C using a multi-layer ANN. My inputs are 2D combinations of time series using 1 hour of A and 30 minutes of B for prediction.
Assume we are predicting C at time t = 0, then the input (x) is as follows:
x0 = [A(t=-60), A(t=-59) ... A(t=0), B(t=-30), B(t=-29) ... B(t=0)]

Then for t = 1,
x1 = [A(t=-59), A(t=-58) ... A(t=1), B(t=-29), B(t=-28) ... B(t=1)]

As you can see, inputs 0 and 1 have overlapping time history, and therefore, would have data leakage when split into a train, test and validation set like so:
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=test_split, random_state=64, shuffle=True)

x_val, x_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(x_test, y_test, test_size=val_split, random_state=64, shuffle=True)

One clear way to solve this issue is to make shuffle=False when splitting the dataset and then shuffling the training set in the data loader, which I do here after converting to torch tensors:
# training data loading
train_data = TensorDataset(x_train_tensor, y_train_tensor)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# validation data loading
val_data = TensorDataset(x_val_tensor, y_val_tensor)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

The problem is that when I do not shuffle on the train/test/split, my model is awful. Suspiciously awful (e.g. correlation coefficient on the test set of -0.02). I say suspicious as I know the my predictors are statistically correlated with my target, that even if the model was not performing well I would still get better metrics than what I am seeing.
Since I do not shuffle my data during splitting, I suspect that there is important information later on in time that is in the test set that my model would need in training. I am not sure. It just seems to be performing too poorly that I think there is an issue I am not seeing.
Is there a better way to split my dataset to preserve time history and prevent major data leakage?
Edit: I also should add that I run the model through a hyperparameter tuning script, so the dataset gets to train with a variety of parameters. The results are consistently awful.

Are there some temporal dynamics that you are failing to account for? So the val/test sets are sufficiently different to the training set that training is not useful?
Also, given the massive overlap, you're possibly using too many input timesteps. If the difference in inputs between C(t=0) and C(t=1) is only removing A(t=-60), B(t=-30) and adding A(t=1) and B(t=1), might the rest of the inputs just be adding noise/complexity to your task?

@Téo, thank you for your reply! I am unsure at the moment if I am missing anything regarding to temporal dynamics. The idea is that my model uses X hr time history of the predictors to predict C. The hour scale is chosen because of the nature of the data which has microscale and macrosale properties captured over minutes and hours that may be important for prediction. I used 60 and 30 here, but I also experiment with 3-5 hour timescales.

I think broadly your approach should be correct, though since it doesn't work, it suggests some issue with your process. If there is some temporal effect you aren't capturing properly, I might suggest doing a more custom approach to the train-val-test split.
What you could do is split your data into n subsets, each with a gap in time between them. The gap has to be minimum 1hr to avoid overlap. Though really you should consider something like the auto-correlation timescales of A, B, and C, to determine what might lead to data leakage.
I would do something like the following:
Choose how long a continuous segment should be. Let's say 5 hours for example. In your dataset this would correspond to 300 samples.
Choose how long your gap should be. Minimum 1hr - but ideally informed by the auto-correlation of A/B/C. Let's say 2 hours for example.
Select your data subsets. E.g., if you have your data in an array:
n_segments = len(x) // (300 + 120)
segments = [x[i*300 + i*120 : i*300 + i*120 + 300] for i in range(n_segments)  

Where this should only yield the 5 hours (300 minutes) for each cycle of segment and gap (2 hours - 120 minutes).
Then you just need to assign these to train/val/test, and you should be able to do that by a random sample, since now you shouldn't have a problem of data leakage. Though you do obviously have to concatenate them back into singular arrays rather than the current sub-arrays in the list.
